# SQL Server - "must declare scalar variable" error message even though I have just declared it

Tags: sql-server, variables, sql-server-2014, variable-declaration

I am trying to write a script in SQL Server 2014 that imports a series of files where the date is in the file name. I will run this every day, with daily exports that have the respective date in their file name. I'd like to set the date as a variable to avoid having to go through the script and type the date into each filepath for the import statements (there will be around 20 different reports each day).

This is what I have now:

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @engagements VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @findings VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @date = '20180708'
GO

SET @engagements = 'bulk insert dbo.engagements
from ''\\sanascl\users$\MG3976\My Documents\Report Exports\' + @date + '-Engagements_sqltest.txt''
WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    fieldterminator = ''\t'',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
    )
'
GO

SET @findings = 'bulk insert dbo.findings
from ''\\sanascl\users$\MG3976\My Documents\Report Exports\' + @date + '-findings_sql.txt''
WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    fieldterminator = ''\t'',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
    )
'
GO

EXEC(@engagements)
GO
EXEC(@findings)
GO
```

However, when I run this I get

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
>   Must declare scalar variable "@date"

and that error message repeats for each line where the `@date` variable is called. Additionally, the error repeats for the other variables at their respective `Exec` statements.

I've tried rearranging the declarations and set statements, but nothing is working- PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Your problem are the `GO` statements; each one of them starts a whole new code block ignoring the previous one

Comment: Might want to looking into parametrise, or similar. If `date` is an input variables let, uou're wide open to injection.

Comment: You're also going to get errors on your `WITH` statements, as you didn't finish any of your statements with a semicolon (`;`). You should be terminating each statement with one, not doing so is a deprecated feature. `WITH` statements, however, require the previous statement to be terminated. *(Note: `;` is not a "beginningator, like some believe. Using `;WITH` is not the solution, terminating your statements correctly is.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GO in SQL Server executes the batch and wipes out your variables.

```
DECLARE @testing INT = 0

SELECT @testing 

GO 

SELECT @testing
```

Remove it and it will work

```
DECLARE @testing INT = 0

SELECT @testing 
SELECT @testing
```